# If given: $0.745355992 \approx \frac{\sqrt{a}}{b} $ is it possible to find $a$ and $b$?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$\frac{\sqrt{5}}{3} = 0.745355992$ to 9 decimal places.

If I had been given the number 0.745355992 to start with and was asked to write it in the form $\frac{\sqrt{a}}{b}$ is it possible to approximate values for $a$ and $b$?

Comment: The quantity $a = 0.745\ldots$ satisfies $a^2 \approx 0.\overline{5} = \frac{5}{9}$, so $a \approx \sqrt{\frac{5}{9}} = \frac{\sqrt 5}{3}$.

Comment: Boring answer: you could always take the number after the decimal point, square it, and let that be $a$; then let $b$ be an appropriate power of 10. However, once you restrict yourself appropriately (i.e., given $n$ decimal digits, can I find $a,b$ with $a < f(n)$ for $f$ some function), the question again becomes deep and interesting.

Comment: Basically, this asks for a generalization of [Continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) approximations, where instead of $a/b$, you seek $a/b^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you are given a positive real number $\alpha$, and you want to approximate it by $\sqrt a/b$. Here is a systematic approach to the problem:

1. find the continued-fraction approximants $(p_1/q_1,p_2/q_2,\ldots)$ of $\alpha^2$ ([this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Calculating_continued_fraction_representations) tells you how);
2. express each $p_i/q_i$ as $r_i/s_i^2$ by multiplying $p_i$ and $q_i$ by the square-free part of $q_i$;
3. pick the element $r_i/s_i^2$ that best meets your requirements.

Part 3 is obviously not rigorous, but if $\alpha$ is close enough to a number of the form $\sqrt a/b$, then $a/b^2$ will show up in the sequence.

**Worked example:** here $\alpha=0.745355992$, so $\alpha^2=0.555555554810304064$. You can see instantly that $5/9$ is an excellent approximation, but let's go through the motions:

$0.555555554810304064$
Integral part is $0$: $\alpha^2=[0;\ldots]$

Subtract integral part and invert:
$1.8000000024146148358790915543479$
Integral part is $1$: $\alpha^2=[0;1,\ldots]$

Subtract integral part and invert:
$1.2499999962271643303263506729912$
Integral part is $1$: $\alpha^2=[0;1,1,\ldots]$

Subtract integral part and invert:
$4.000000060365371625772898363428$
Integral part is $4$: $\alpha^2=[0;1,1,4,\ldots]$

Subtract integral part and invert:
$16565788.846615028668956002524823$
Integral part is $16565788$: $\alpha^2=[0;1,1,4,16565788,\ldots]$

Such a huge integral part means $[0;1,1,4]$ is a very good aproximation to $\alpha^2$.

The continued-fraction approximants are:
$[0;1]=1$
$[0;1,1]=1/2$
$[0;1,1,4]=5/9$
$[0;1,1,4,16565788]=$ some complicated fraction very close to $5/9$

Expressing these approximants $(1,1/2,5/9)$ in the form $a/b^2$ gives $(1,2/4,5/9)$, so the candidates for $\alpha=\sqrt a/b$ are $1,\sqrt 2/2,$ and $\sqrt 5/3$. Now back-checking reveals that $\sqrt 5/3$ is indeed $0.745355992$ to nine significant figures, which is what you wanted.

Just for fun, you might like to try this slightly more challenging example:

$$\alpha=0.327515550754707171889380$$

Answer (score 8):

The problem would have infinitely many solutions. If $\sqrt a/b$ is a solution, so it is
$$\frac{\sqrt{10^{50}a+1}}{10^{25}b}$$

A good way to obtain a pair of relatively small values for $a$ and $b$ could be the following.

Let $x$ be areal number. We want to approximate it with an expression of the form $\sqrt a /b$

With continued fractions method, approximate $x^2\approx p/q$. Then
$$x\approx \sqrt{\frac pq}=\frac{\sqrt {pq}}q$$

Comment: Can we prove that $p$ and $q$ provide optimal approximations foro $x$? (It is known for $x^2$)

Answer (score 6):

There are many possibilities, of course, but we can find the (in one sense) simplest one:

We have that $\frac{a}{b^2}$ is between $0.745355992^2$ and $0.745355993^2$.

The continued fraction representations of these numbers are ([courtesy of Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=continued+fraction+(745355992%2F10%5E9)%5E2)):
$$ \Bigl(\frac{745355992}{10^9}\Bigr)^2 = [0; 1, 1, 4, 16565788, 1, 5, 1, 1, 12, 3, 2, 2, 1, 5, 2, 2108] \\
\Bigl(\frac{745355993}{10^9}\Bigr)^2= [0; 1, 1, 3, 1, 16561143, 1, 4, 8, 1, 1, 2, 6, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 7, 6, 1, 16, 10, 1, 17] $$

The simplest rational between the two squares can be found by taking their shared prefix and appending one more than the smaller coefficient at the first point of difference:
$$ [0;1,1,\min(4,3)+1] = [0;1,1,4] = \frac{5}{9} $$
Now we need to make the denominator of this a perfect square -- this is already the case but it were not, we could multiply the missing prime factors into both numerator and denominator. And so we get
$$ 0.745355992 \le \frac{\sqrt 5}{3} \le 0.745355993 $$

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [LLL algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm#Applications), Wikipedia explains how to use it well enough. This answer [mentions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38763/how-to-find-a-polynomial-from-a-given-root/38777#38777) the same idea.

You can use [the Inverse Symbolic Calculator](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/standard) if you don't wish to implement it yourself.